# React JS scrollIntoView() not scrolling all the way down

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small starter React JS project I'm working on where a user types text into a field, the text appears above the field in a fixed height box, and the content in that box scrolls down so that the last element added is always visible. (Essentially like a chat box.)

I've attempted to do this using .scrollIntoView(), but for some reason it doesn't scroll all the way to the bottom of the box. Instead it always stays a few pixels from the bottom. (Firefox 88 on macOS Big Sur)

I have a *very* stripped down demo of what's happening here: https://ui7bx.csb.app/

You can view the source code below and edit it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-dawn-ui7bx?file=/src/index.js:0-1383

I'm baffled as to what could be going wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles.css";

class Blog extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.sendMsg = this.sendMsg.bind(this);
    this.textInput = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      posts: [
        {content: "This is decent sized post"},
        {content:"Another post that is a little longer and extends the boundaries of space and time"}
      ]
    };
  }
  sendMsg(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // stop page from refreshing
    // update state with new post
    let posts = this.state.posts;
    const content = this.textInput.current.value; // get field value
    posts.push({content: content});
    this.setState({ posts: posts });

    //scroll down to the bottom
    this.msgEnd.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
  }
  render() {
    const msgList = this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
      return (
        <div className={"postWrapper"} key={index}>{post.content}</div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="list">
          {msgList}
          <div ref={el => {this.msgEnd = el; }}></div>
        </div>
        <form id="chatForm">
          <input type="text" ref={this.textInput} />
          <button onClick={this.sendMsg}>Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Blog />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Interesting, other than the first message that "overflows" it appears to consistently scroll the bottom of the messages into view. Chrome 83 MacOS Mojave.

Comment: @DrewReese Weird - the issue ended up being that I was scrolling before the element had fully rendered. Maybe Chrome 83 is just faster than Firefox at rendering? :)

Comment: Yup, once @Anthony answered it was overtly obvious you had the order mixed up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need the scroll to happen *after* the posts have been updated, so they are all (including the new one that is added in the `sendMsg()` method) rendered and the `msgEnd ref` is up to date.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    //maybe add conditional logic to only scroll when the posts have changed
    this.msgEnd.scrollIntoView({
      block: "nearest",
      inline: "center",
      behavior: "smooth",
      alignToTop: false
    });
  }
```

Comment: Ah! That’s a good thought. How would you recommend that I check that the new “post” has fully rendered?

Comment: it will have if `componentDidUpdate` is invoked, since your `state` was updated when `sendMsg()` was called

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I'm rather new to ReactJS so I didn't realize that **componentDidUpdate** was a React method (and not some custom method you had written.) This did the trick! I imagine I can use **prevState** and the current state to check if I should call the **scrollIntoView** code.

Comment: yep you can use `prevState` to verify whether you want to scroll again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the scrollIntoView not work in some cases.
Mention in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#notes

> The element may not be scrolled completely to the top or bottom depending on the layout of other elements.

You can use `scrollTop` attribute to make it works.
Sample code that always works for me:

```
const targetElement = mainEl.querySelector('#' + itemElement)
    if (targetElement) {
      mainEl.scrollTop = targetElement.offsetTop
    }
```